# JavaFX8 ChoiceBox transparent?

Tags: java, css, styling, javafx-8

I want to make a ChoiceBox transparent, so that it looks like a label. Is it possible to hide the arrow on the right and the background? The Popup should be like default.
Which CSS-Classes do I have to use here?

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Website for this kind of information on css in jfx: [CSS Reference Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html)

Here is how you can manipulate the nodes inside of a coice box:

```
.choice-box > .open-button > .arrow{
    /* Example: -fx-opacity: 0; */
}
```

You basically just need to step through all nodes that are inside the choicebox to be able to manipulate the arrow.

If you need any further information i will provide it if i can :)

Hope it helps,
Laurenz

EDIT: that's the full solution:

```
.choice-box > .open-button > .arrow{
    -fx-opacity: 0;
}

.choice-box{
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
```

EDIT2: how to use css on nodes with applied id/class?

```
    #mycombobox > .open-button > .arrow{
        -fx-opacity: 0;
    }

    #mycombobox{
        -fx-background-color: transparent;
    }
```

Use with CSS class:

```
    .mycombobox > .open-button > .arrow{
        -fx-opacity: 0;
    }

    .mycombobox{
        -fx-background-color: transparent;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That's exactly what I searched for. CSS Reference Guide is also bookmarked now (I'm feeling bad for not finding it on my own...).

Comment: One more question: How do I use this for only one and not all choiceboxes? So that one looks transparent and another looks like standard?

Comment: set the css id or the css class of that element:
cb.setId("mycombobox");
or
cb.getStyleClass().add("mycombobox");

Note that ID's cannot be used on multiple nodes; classes can. -- I'll add an example to my answer.

Comment: Thanks! I would upvote your answer one more time if it's possible! :-)